# Android Studio Opening an activity

Tags: android-studio, android-activity

I am trying to open an activity with in an activity. I succeeded to do to from MainActivity but for some reason, this wont allow me to do so again.

I am very new to this, please help me.

```
package com.example.edonfreiner.siddur;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Davening extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button shacharisButton, minchaButton, maarivButton;

    public void openShacharis() {
        shacharisButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.shacharis);
        shacharisButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                Intent open = new Intent(Davening.this, Shacharis.class);

                startActivity(open);



            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_davening);

        openShacharis();


    }
}
```

This is the code to my class, there are no errors, meaning all buttons and references exist in the XML file.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have your `Shacharis` activity declared on your android manifest? Do you have any logs?

Comment: I did not, thank you very much. What exactly does that do?

Answer (score 0):

The logic you built is mistaken, cause you are calling a function in your onCreate  that will not activate the onClick inside it. And when you click your object, it does not activate the onClick because this is encapsulated inside openShacharis. So the solution is to take off onClick from openShacharis, this way:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_davening);

    shacharisButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.shacharis);
    shacharisButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openShacharis();
        }
    });
}

public void openShacharis() {
    Intent open = new Intent(Davening.this, Shacharis.class);
    startActivity(open);
}
```

Comment: The names used on the code were misleading, but the logic was correct. During `onCreate` he calls `openShacharis` which sets the click listener with the callback for opening the activity.
I agree with you on the naming, since his `openShacharis` it's not opening but just registering the listener, but that doesn't seem the root cause of his problem.

Answer (score 0):

All activities need to be registered on the Android Manifest.
As you stated on your comment, if you don't have it registered, it won't open.

[This documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) will probably help you. In particular the part where it `Adds the required <activity> element in AndroidManifest.xml.`

Comment: It' strange because OP said **there are no errors**. If not registered on Manifest, error would be raised. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: You are right, if the activity is not registered on the manifest, you'll get an error on the logs. My assumption is that OP missed it, since it doesn't make the app crash or causes any compilation warning.